# Grails Resources plugin - Set absolute URL to resources

Tags: css, grails, resources

I am using the resources plugin (1.2.8) to load my css and js files. it work great but the thing is that the URLs are "relative".

Example:

```
<r:require module="core"/>
```

I get something like this

```
<script src="/app/static/js/core.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="/app/static/css/core.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen, projection">
```

But i want the URL to be **ABSOLUTE**. Something like this:

```
<script src="http://myServer.com/app/static/js/core.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

The behaviour i am looking is the same as the "absolute" option when using grails resources

```
<g:resource dir="css" file="main.css" absolute="true" />
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: why would you like it this way?

Comment: to avoid Relative Path Overwrite attack @KamilMikolajczyk

Comment: do you think it's possible in grails application?

Comment: I don't see anything in grails that could avoid it. But maybe i am missing something...